# Unable Register Kie Server (No Remote Servers) in Workbench (Kie-WB 6.4.0 in WildFly 8.2.1)

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-wb, kie-server

Problem with configuring kie-wb with kie-server.

I've wildfly 8.2.1 with Kie-server installed to it on one machine.
For this I've created two users using adduser.bat:
Management User 
User :- alpha1
passwrod :- password@1
role :- admin,kie-server

Application User
User :- alpha2
password :- password@1
role :- admin,kie-server,rest-all

I am running this server using this command :-

**standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://this-machine-ip:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller  -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=alpha2 -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=password@1**

In standalone.xml I've done changes for **interfaces** tag to allow **any-ipv4-address**

I've another machine with wildfly 8.2.1 and Kie-WB installed to it.
For this also I've created two users using adduser.bat:
Management User 
User :- alpha3
passwrod :- password@1
role :- admin,kie-server

Application User
User :- alpha4
password@1
role :- admin,kie-server,rest-all

I am running this server using this command :-

**standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml**

**Question :-** 
Sequence of execution is I am launching Kie-Server first,now when my Kie-Server is up I am running Kie-WB.
In kie-WB when I am creating a server template I am not getting this kie-server there.
Although while creating Server template I am using the name of kie.server.id (i.e. "wildfly-kieserver" in my case)
Even in remote servers I am not seeing any remote server.

Please let me know if I am missing anything on configuration end or doing something wrong here.

Links which I have followed :-
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/drools-setup/dKOySBezWSQ
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/drools-setup/dKOySBezWSQ/UcBV7Wc2EgAJ
http://mswiderski.blogspot.in/2015/09/unified-kie-execution-server-part-3.html
http://blog.athico.com/2015/10/installing-kie-server-and-workbench-on.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
Just required to give Kie-server and Kie-Wb IP at right places.

-Dorg.kie.server.location=http://"IP of machine on which Kie server is installed":8080/kie-server/services/rest/server

-Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://"IP of machine on which Kie-wb is installed":8080/kie-wb/rest/controller

Comment: I am having the same issue. Tried replacing localhost with actual IP besides 127.0.0.1; [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism
 [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/wildfly-kieserver error Connection refused: connect