# Work Bench Controller Not Connecting To Kie Server (Version 7.33)

Tags: jbpm, kie

My question can be thought of as an extension to

[Unable Register Kie Server (No Remote Servers) in Workbench (Kie-WB 6.4.0 in WildFly 8.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527707/unable-register-kie-server-no-remote-servers-in-workbench-kie-wb-6-4-0-in-wil)

The version I have is different from the one in the earlier post. So please bear with me.

After going through tens of blogs and web pages, I am finally here to hear from the experts about what I am doing wrong. I have these two war files that are deployed on Wildfly 18.0.1.Final.

- kie-server-7.33.0.Final-ee7.war (taken from kie-server-distribution-7.33.0.Final.zip and renamed to kie-server.war)
- business-central-7.33.0.Final-wildfly14.war (renamed to business-central.war)

I have set up the users thus (windows server):

$ add-user.bat -a -u kieserver -p kieserver1! -g kie-server

$ add-user.bat -a -u workbench -p workbench! -g admin,kie-server

I followed this blog: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-jbpm/drools/getting-started-with-business-central-workbench

And getting these errors:

```
16:56:42,003 INFO  [org.kie.server.controller.websocket.client.WebSocketKieServerControllerImpl] 
    (KieServer-ControllerConnect) Kie Server points to non Web Socket controller 
   'http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller', using default REST mechanism

   16:56:47,006 WARN  [org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl] (KieServer- 
   ControllerConnect) Exception encountered while syncing with controller at 
   http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/controller/server/wildfly-kieserver error Read timed out
```

I don't see the remote server in the Workbench when I try to deploy a drools example taken from the same blog post.

Quite frankly, I am jealous of all the people having success with this kind of controller-server configuration. I could use REST using curl or something appropriate to deploy my project but I like the WorkBench so much that I would like to see if I can make it work.

The noteworthy blogpost I referred to was http://blog.athico.com/2015/10/installing-kie-server-and-workbench-on.html

Here are my JAVA_OPTS setting in standalong.conf.bat

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx2G -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2G -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-wb/rest/controller -Dorg.kie.server.controller.user=workbench -Dorg.kie.server.controller.pwd=workbench! -Dorg.kie.server.user=kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.pwd=kieserver1!"
```

It took me some time to figure out the JAVA_OPTS memory settings that won't cause outofmemory errors.
Please note that I am over-riding JAVA_OPTS by launching the wildfly like so:

```
D:\wildfly-18.0.1.Final\bin>standalone.bat --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.server.id=wildfly-kieserver -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://127.0.0.1:8080/kie-server-ee7/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://127.0.0.1:8080/business-central/rest/controller
```

Another thing, I have no idea what the different controllers (ee7, webc, etc.) are meant for. Having tried them, I can say I get "Forbidden" error. I am quite a novice at JBPM but not shy of Java (reading the source is another project for another day).

If I am missing something, please shoot.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this yet

Answer (score -1):

Did these 2 things and the problem is resolved:

1. Deleted wildfly-kieserver.xml in the Wildfly bin folder
2. Removed .niogit in the same folder and its subdirectories

Then started the Wildfly server same as before with an extra option

-b 0.0.0.0

I don't know exactly what fixed the issue. I would like to hear from the people reading this, if any, so that I can learn something.

Thanks

Comment: Deleting this folder .niogit  will delete the Whole workspace

Comment: the solution will be shrouded in mystery !! .. Does not work for me -